# Custom related name for a Django model parent link?

Tags: python, django, metaclass

I am working on a Django project that needs to be extensible. So for that sake I created a series of base models (some abstract, some not) in a core app and all kinds of template methods so that new plugin apps for the project could be developed with little effort.

Problem is, I have a couple different plugin apps that contain models with the same name and the same superclass from the core app. I feel like this are models that would exist for only a handful of apps with completely distinct independent implementations and it wouldn't really make sense to have a single common class in the core app.

Core app:

```
class MyBaseClass(models.Model):
    """
    This is the base class.
    """
    pass
```

Plugin app 1:

```
class MySubclass(MyBaseClass):
    """
    Some subclass.
    """
    pass
```

Plugin app 2:

```
class MySubclass(MyBaseClass):
    """
    Some other subclass.
    """
    pass
```

This does not work because there is a clash in the related names created for the parent link, which as far as I can tell is just a OneToOneField created by the ModelBase metaclass. I feel like this could be avoided just by including the app's name in the related name, but I don't know if there is a pragmatically sound way to do that.

Since these plugin apps would be created by different people I feel like I should handle class name collisions, specially since I don't think they are unlikely to occur.

Is there a way to specify the related name for the parent link field? Any alternative ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the parent link in your subclass:

```
class MySubclass(MyBaseClass):
    mybaseclass = models.OneToOneField(MyBaseClass, parent_link=True, related_name='thissubclass')
```